# get selected value of html foaded from jquery.load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jquery.load() to get an html code. This html is a form with js inside.

My problem, I want to get selected value of an input inside this form, but it returned "" even if there is an selected value..

Main-page.html:

```
url = "http://url-to-get-info-div";    
$('#info').load(url);
```

The Main-page.html then has then a form and script inside

```
<div id="info">
<select name="nature" title="" required="" class="form-control" id="id_nature">
  <option value="">---------</option>
  <option value="a-specifier">A spécifier</option>
  <option value="perte">Perte</option>
  <option value="dommage">Dommage</option>
  <option value="retard" selected="">Retard</option>
  <option value="non-livre">Contestation livraison</option>

  </select>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
----some script who need $("#id_nature)---
    function calcul_indemnisation(nature_litige = $("#id_nature").val()){
        ---some work who use id_nature value---
        return montant_indemnisation
     }
    $("#calcul_indemnisation").click(function(){
        montant_indemnisation = calcul_indemnisation();
    }
</script>
```

the problem is when a click on the button "#calcul_indemnisation, the return value is not correct because id_nature value is not got correctly

Comment: You said currently you get "". Please show your current code to get the select value

Comment: I updated the code

Answer (score 0):

I resolve it ! In fact, I had another select with the same id further in the code! so there was a conflict with the id name

Answer (score -1):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to wire up generated elements, or use [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) syntax and give one function as parameter.

```js
function calcul_indemnisation(){
  var option = $('#id_nature').find(':selected');
  
  var value = option.val();
  var text = option.text();
  
  //perform the calculations
  
  return value;
};

//.load(url, function)
$('#info').load('url-you-need', function(){
  //create click event in #calcul_indemnisation
  $('#calcul_indemnisation').click(function(){
    console.clear();
    console.log('triggered with load .click(): ' + calcul_indemnisation());
  });
});

//create click event on #calcul_indemnisation inside #info.
$('#info').on('click','#calcul_indemnisation',function(){
  let montant_indemnisation = calcul_indemnisation();
  console.log('triggered with .on() click: ' + montant_indemnisation);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="info">
<select name="nature" title="" required="" class="form-control" id="id_nature">
  <option value="">---------</option>
  <option value="a-specifier">A spécifier</option>
  <option value="perte">Perte</option>
  <option value="dommage">Dommage</option>
  <option value="retard" selected="">Retard</option>
  <option value="non-livre">Contestation livraison</option>

  </select>
  
  <input type="button" id="calcul_indemnisation" value="Click me!"/>
</div>
```

Comment: In fact, I then have a button who calls a function to do some operation with #id_nature

Comment: Use `$(buttonId).click()` then.

Comment: Thank you, I had more explaination on the question, sorry my english is not very good

Comment: It's okay. Edited the answer, hope it helps. :)

Comment: I tried your code but I still have "" in value :/ I think that because the code is loaded from load(), and the DOM doesn't see $('#id_nature')

Comment: still don't work :( the weird thing is that I have an other select which I am able to get !

Comment: Then try using [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) syntax: `$('#info').load(url, function(){ $('#calcul_indemnisation').click(function() { /*functions you need*/ } });`